# How can I quickly return back to the last working directory?

Tags: bash, cd-command, pwd

All too often I find myself cycling between two directories to perform different tasks. The directories don't always have an easy-to-use relative path between them. As a result it is quite cumbersome to have to specify a directory path that is essentially the previous working directory.

Is there a command by which I can easily return back to the previous working directory?

Comment: `pushd`, `popd`, `dirs`

Comment: @Gnouc : I didn't find that question when I had searched. Thanks for finding it

Answer (score 3):

Bash utilizes a shell variable `$OLDPWD` which (as the name suggests) stores the old value of the present working directory `$PWD`.

Also, the man page entry for [Bourne shell built-ins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) has this to say about `cd`:

> An argument of `-` is equivalent to `$OLDPWD`.

Which means that one could simply type

```
$ cd -
```

to mean

```
$ cd $OLDPWD
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cd -` or `cd $OLDPWD`. But I suggest to use `pushd` and `popd`.These utilities keep what is called a directory stack.

`pushd dir`:You will change directory to `dir` and save dir in the stack. If you do another `pushd dir4`, then `dir4` will be added to the directory stack.

`popd`:It allows you to undo the directory changes. By giving a `popd` command, the last directory pushed in the stack (which is your current directory) will be removed, you will change directory to the second directory which becomes the top of the stack.

`dirs -v`: To see the contents of the directory stack.

If you know the stack concept then it'll be very much easy to understand.